# PySpark read.parquet vs Pandas read_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am not seeing significantly faster read times using PySpark read.parquet vs. Pandas read_parquet. I am trying to read 4 parquet files each 2-3 MB using a for loop and do some basic aggregation.

Here is my PySpark code:

```
ts_dfs = []
# For loop to collect building time series and append to empty dataframe
start = time.time()
for id in ids[0:4]:
    # Make the path to the data
    timeseries_path = f'{dataset_path}/timeseries_individual_buildings/by_county/upgrade=0/county={id[0]}'
    # Read the data and select columns of interest
    ts_data_df = spark.read.parquet(timeseries_path).select('`bldg_id`', '`out.electricity.heating.energy_consumption`', '`timestamp`')
    # Aggregate by month
    ts_data_df = ts_data_df \
    .groupBy(f.month('timestamp').alias('month'),'bldg_id') \
    .agg(f.sum('`out.electricity.heating.energy_consumption`').alias('kWh'))
    # Append to empty list
    ts_dfs.append(ts_data_df)
# Combine all dfs
ts = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, ts_dfs)
end = time.time()
print ("Time elapsed:", end - start)
```

Time elapsed: 5.127371788024902

Here is my Pandas code:

```
#Download time series of all buildings with the ids we want:
cols = {'timestamp','out.electricity.heating.energy_consumption'}
ts_dfs = []
start = time.time()
for id in ids[0:4]:
    # Make the path to the data
    timeseries_path = f'{dataset_path}/timeseries_individual_buildings/by_county/upgrade=0/county={id[0]}'
    # Read the data and columns of interest
    ts_data_df = pd.read_parquet(timeseries_path, columns = cols)
    # Some date processing
    ts_data_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ts_data_df['timestamp'])
    ts_data_df['month'] = ts_data_df['date'].dt.month
    # Aggregate by month
    ts_data_df = ts_data_df.groupby(['month','bldg_id'], as_index = False).agg(sum = ('out.electricity.heating.energy_consumption','sum'))
    # Append to empty list
    ts_dfs.append(ts_data_df)
# Concatenate all the dfs:
all_ts_df = pd.concat(ts_dfs)
end = time.time()
print ("Time elapsed:", end - start)
```

Time elapsed: 40.325382232666016

Frankly I would expect Spark to finish this significantly faster given that the files are so small. I'm running this in a Jupyter Notebook and my spark configuration is as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Configure prior to creating context
conf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
.setAppName('appName') \
.setMaster('local[*]') \
.setAll([
    ("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true"),
    ("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") 
])

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

My machine has 16 gb of ram and 8 cores, so there should be some parallelization going on given this configuration, correct?

Additionally, when I try to convert the above pyspark DataFrame to pandas, it doubles the amount of time even though the resulting dataframe is only 48 rows and 3 columns. Is there any .persist() or .cache() I can do to speed things up? Any changes to my PySpark configuration that would better leverage my computing power?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to speed it up to 1/8th the time using pyspark, which seems significant to me, especially over such a small footprint (12MB total?) What kind of performance difference were you expecting to see? (Also, using the timeit module can give more accurate code timings)

Comment: Perhaps it would be more appropriate to include the total PySpark run time including the conversion to a pandas DF, since that is the result I ultimately want. Including that additional step, it's 1/4 of the Pandas run time. 

Point take, though. Perhaps my expectations of pyspark were too high. Also, this page suggests that the runtimes diverge as the datasets get larger?

https://databricks.com/blog/2018/05/03/benchmarking-apache-spark-on-a-single-node-machine.html

Comment: Remember that pyspark, at its core, is designed to parallelize _big data_ operations across servers (a la spark), on the order of gigabytes to terabytes, not megabytes that fit snugly within the bounds of your own RAM and processor. Given the time it takes to distribute and parallelize the data stream within your own machine, on this small data and reasonably simple operations, I'd still call the speed-up significant (not that there mightn't be things you could to do to speed it further, but I can't see much based on what you've posted)

Comment: That makes sense. I should note that I intend to download far more than 4 dataframes in the for loop via PySpark (eventually I have to get thousands), I have just been using 4 here to test the code and get a general sense of how long things will take.

Comment: Then it seems like you're doing the right thing, developing in small-scale and then expanding later once your pipeline is built. But it seems like perhaps [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) to try to `persist` or `cache` what fit's within a few cycles and entirely within memory. Those methods exist for a reason, but that reason may not be apparent until you _need_ to use them. Perhaps if you start drawing _more_ data than will fit in local and then see where your bottlenecks are?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on when to cache? I can't decide if each dataframe should be cached before aggregation, after aggregation and before appending, or after they've been combined into on dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240738/discussion-between-tsgsteele-and-g-anderson).